# Concatenation of different types in Java

Tags: java, string, casting, formatting

I know, the question is very simple. But there are some small details that I need to fully understand (it is very important to understand what is happening in the background). Let's look at the piece code first. Why 2 consecutive "+" signs do not cause error here? Or is there an invisible 0 between those 2 "+'s"? In the first case, the reason the character is cast to the integer is 2 consecutive "+" signs, right?

```
public class AppleApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Apple is " + + '2' + " USD");
        // OUTPUT:   Apple is 50 USD
        System.out.println("Apple is " + + 2 + " USD");
        // OUTPUT:   Apple is 2 USD
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Apple is " + + 2 + " USD"` is 'parsed' as follows:

`("Apple is " + (+2) + " USD"` and `+2` is just.. 2. Just like `int x = +2;` is legit, so is that.

The same applies to `+ + '2'`, because in java, characters are numbers (even where strings) aren't. '2' is the number `0x32` (the unicode code of the character 2).

---

`char` is a bit of a bizarre type; it's *numeric*. Specifically, a char represents a number between 0 and 65535, just like a byte is -128 to +127, and a short is from -32768 to +32767, and int is from -2147483648 to 2147483647.

Eventhough it is a number, all relevant methods that print things treat the number as a unicode value: They look up the number in the unicode table and show the character instead, i.e.:

```
char c = 65;
System.out.println(c);
```

prints `A`. That's not because of anything inherent in `char`, it's because of the `println` method.

In java, `byte`, `short`, and `char` are inferior: Many operations cannot be done on them, instead they're all converted to int first. That's because the spec says this.

Hence, `+'A'` is an expression that is of type `int`. A bit weird, but, spec says so. Hence, `System.out.println(+'A')` prints 65, because it calsl the `int` version of `println` which just prints 65, vs. `System.out.println('A');` which calls the `char` version, which prints `'A'`.

Comment: **(+2)** -> + is unary operator, right? And **(+'2')** ->and here to make positive it cast (change) into int, right? 
Thanks! interchanging between int and char a bit confusing me.

Comment: @elvintaghizade14 I added a bunch of text to this answer to explain char v int

Comment: There could be no better explanation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

A `char` is a number, so read it as `"Apple is " + (+'2') + " USD"`.

Same for the case with the integer.

Comment: Thanks! interchanging between int and char a bit confusing me.